# custom access domain minio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I have a minIO S3 compatible instance for storing images that are uploaded to my web application. I have heard that it would be possible to generate a custom link to access a file directly from minio.
My preferred solution would be to have one cluster running my backend, and another cluster running minio. Now when a user wants to upload an image, the backend generates a custom link for the frontend to push the images. Ideally, this link could be generated and is time limited or secured with an access key.
The same would be desirable for access to the images. So if a user wants to view the images later, the backend generates a new link and this link could be used directly as an image link in the frontend (same with time restriction or access key). This would reduce the network load on my application cluster.

Is there any way to implement something like this or any other approach that would produce a similar result

Answer (score 0):

So I can't answer the architecture/topology questions, but in general there are two features I think you can use from the perspective of temporary access:

1. Presigned URLs - you can generate these via the S3 API or by using a CLI hook ( [`mc share`](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-share-download.html) )
2. The [STS API](https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/assume-role.md) for generating temporary credentials for a given user

Either would support expiring credentials or access.